# jQuery UI not working on dynamically created DOM elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have jQuery UI draggable and resizable working. I'm creating a div inside my another div (#canvas) using a button onClick function. Draggable works on the div I added statically, but it doesn't work on the div that gets appended with the onClick function. Any idea why?

JS

```
// Draw rectangle
function drawRect(){
    var rectangle = document.createElement('div');
    rectangle.className = 'rectangle ui-draggable ui-resizable ui-selectable';
    rectangle.style.width = "200px";
    rectangle.style.height = "200px";
    rectangle.style.position = "absolute";

    // Define resize handles
    var n = document.createElement('div');
    n.className = 'ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-n';
    var e = document.createElement('div');
    e.className = 'ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e';
    var s = document.createElement('div');
    s.className = 'ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s';
    var w = document.createElement('div');
    w.className = 'ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-w';

    // Build resize handles
    rectangle.appendChild(n);
    rectangle.appendChild(e);
    rectangle.appendChild(s);
    rectangle.appendChild(w);

    // Build div
    document.getElementById("canvas").appendChild(rectangle);
}
```

jQuery Bind

```
jQuery(function($) {

    // Make boxes draggable
    $('.rectangle').draggable();

    // Make elements resizable
    $('.rectangle').resizable({

    // Set custom resize handles
    handles: {'n': '.ui-resizable-n', 'e': '.ui-resizable-e', 's': '.ui-resizable-s', 'w': '.ui-resizable-w' },

    // Recalculate dimensions from pixels to percentages
    stop: function(e, ui) {
      var parent = ui.element.parent();
      ui.element.css({
          width: ui.element.width()/parent.width()*100+"%",
          height: ui.element.height()/parent.height()*100+"%"
      });
    }
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="canvas">
    <div class="rectangle ui-draggable ui-resizable ui-selectable"></div>
</div>

<button onClick="drawRect();">click here</button>
```

Comment: First of all you are using JqueryUi but not using jquery? Where is the code where you bind the draggable event?

Comment: @fatman I added the jQuery bind code. I've no idea how to write JS mate, hence the JS and jQuery mix :)

Comment: closing `>` is missing in html line `<div class="rectangle ui-draggable ui-resizable ui-selectable"></div`

Comment: @UDB Thanks, I've edited question. The code in the question is way different to what I actually have, for brevity. So things like missing tags are probably not the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The element which are added dynamically will not the watched by jQuery you have call `draggable` and `resizable` on the newly added elements try this.

```
function drawRect(){
    var rectangle = document.createElement('div');
    rectangle.className = 'rectangle ui-draggable ui-resizable ui-selectable';
    rectangle.style.width = "200px";
    rectangle.style.height = "200px";
    rectangle.style.position = "absolute";

    // Define resize handles
    var n = document.createElement('div');
    n.className = 'ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-n';
    var e = document.createElement('div');
    e.className = 'ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e';
    var s = document.createElement('div');
    s.className = 'ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s';
    var w = document.createElement('div');
    w.className = 'ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-w';

    // Build resize handles
    rectangle.appendChild(n);
    rectangle.appendChild(e);
    rectangle.appendChild(s);
    rectangle.appendChild(w);

    // Build div
    document.getElementById("canvas").appendChild(rectangle);


$('.rectangle').draggable();

    // Make elements resizable
    $('.rectangle').resizable({

    // Set custom resize handles
    handles: {'n': '.ui-resizable-n', 'e': '.ui-resizable-e', 's': '.ui-resizable-s', 'w': '.ui-resizable-w' },

    // Recalculate dimensions from pixels to percentages
    stop: function(e, ui) {
      var parent = ui.element.parent();
      ui.element.css({
          width: ui.element.width()/parent.width()*100+"%",
          height: ui.element.height()/parent.height()*100+"%"
      });
    }

}
```

Comment: Sexy stuff mate. Thanks so much :)